# Renaming multiple files in windows using command prompt?

Tags: batch-file

I have written a small batch file to move files from one folder to another folder.
copy E:\Source\Test.tif E:\Temp

Is there any way can I rename a file name after it has been moved to temp folder.Like

E:\Source:\TestInd1.tiff.

Please suggest.

Comment: is there a reason you cant do the rename as part of the move command itself? i.e. move e:\source\test.tif e:\temp\testind1.tiff.  actually i am confused because of the use of the word move but the use of the command copy and if you are copying, i am not sure which file you want to rename.

Comment: I have filenames stored in my database table, I am appending copy command and path to the file name in the select statement.I need to rename the file once it is moved.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I mean copying files from one folder to another.

Comment: it would help if you can give a worked example.  because once you copy the file across, the file name is still the same, only the folder name is changed.  you can use "move c:\source\test.tif c:\source\testind1.tiff" to rename the file in the same folder.

Comment: Kinjal are you familiar with SQL statements, if so I will provide sql statement which generates batch file statements.

Comment: @Simhadri kindly make that part of the question so that people who know about this can try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a move and a rename at the same time, yes:

```
move someFile S:\ome\Destination\newName
```